# How to create a plot from the output of a function in R

Tags: r, function, plot

I have a function that calculates the log-likelihood for a vector of expression levels in genes (x); e.g. -0.465, 0.111, -0.437. Sigma value calculated is 0.4717 and a = 0.8861.

```
    loglike <- function(x,theta,sigma,a) {
      sum(log(theta/(2*a)*(x<a)*(x>-a) + (1- 
      theta)*dnorm(x,mean=0.0,sd=sigma)))
    }
```

I want to input a vector of possible values for theta into the function and plot the result of the function with each value for theta. So I thought a for loop to rotate over all the values of theta in the function to create a list of values from the outputs of the loglike function. Then create a plot of theta against the loglike result.

```
   theta <- seq(0,1,0.01)  

   result_ <- c()
   for (i in 1:length(theta)) {
      result <- loglike(x,i,sigma,a)
      result_[i] <- result[i]
   }
```

But this just gives me warning messages:

```
   Warning messages:
   1: In log(theta/(2 * a) * (x < a) * (x > -a) + (1 - theta) * 
   dnorm(x,  :
     NaNs produced
```

I know that the function works because when I use the function one at a time it returns values, such as

```
    loglike(x,0,sigma,a)
    > -333.454234
```

I'm not hugely confident in R as a language, so would really appreciate any help.

Comment: For which values of `theta` the expression craps out?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. For instance, what is the values of `diff_sd`, `U`, etc.

Comment: The error message suggests that your function needs debugging. Why try to plot the output of a function that doesn't quite work?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for adding the values of x, a and sigma: these allowed me to find your bug.

In this loop here:

```r
  for (i in 1:length(theta)) {
      result <- loglike(x,i,sigma,a)
      result_[i] <- result[i]
   }
```

you are inputting `i` as the value of theta to the loglike function. Remember `i` is the index number of the loop that goes from 1 to 101, but you want the theta value at each cycle of the loop, so it should be `theta[i]`.

Also, because your `loglike` function only ever returns a single number, you are storing a single number to `result` but then trying to store `result[i]` to `result_[i]`. When the loop goes past i = 1, you are trying to move a non-existent number.

Here's a full working example:

```r
loglike <- function(x, theta, sigma, a)
{
  sum(log((theta / (2*a)) * (x < a) * (x > -a) +
          (1 - theta) * dnorm(x, mean = 0.0, sd = sigma)))
}

x       <-  0.111
sigma   <-  0.4717
a       <-  0.8861
theta   <- seq(0, 1, 0.01)
result  <- numeric()

for (i in 1:length(theta)) result[i] <- loglike(x, theta[i], sigma, a)
```

Comment: The values for theta are outlined in the vector called the `theta <- seq( 0,1,0.1)`. For `theta =1`, the loglike equation gives `-Inf`. I understand what you are saying, but looking at it from a basic programming stance. I don't understand why it returns all NaN values when using loglike on values of theta at 0.1 gave a result.

Comment: @CharlieVagg are you able to show us the values of x, a and sigma that you are inputting by editing your question? I am sure we can help if we have those. There's nothing wrong with the program per se, But if, for example, you were using a = 0 or negative sigma then you would get a NaN. If we don't have the numbers then we can't replicate the problem, so we don't know what the problem is and can't answer your question.